# Duplicate tags for SciPy optimizations: [scipy-optimize] and [scipy-optimize-minimize]

Tags: discussion, support, tags

For SciPy optimization questions, there are two tags: [scipy-optimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scipy-optimize) and [scipy-optimize-minimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scipy-optimize-minimize).
Although the second tag is a bit more specific (refers to minimization), but it is less popular, it does not have a wiki and the first tag addresses minimization problems just fine.

Wouldn't it make more sense to merge these two?

Comment: With the wiki for [scipy-optimize](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scipy-optimize/info) stating "Tag used for questions regarding minimizing or maximizing objective functions ..." I do feel like [scipy-optimize-minimize](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scipy-optimize-minimize/info) is a bit redundant and doesn't add any more context that what the former tag represents.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we need a separate tag for `scipy.optimize`, and we definitely don't need a tag for `scipy.optimize.minimize`. [scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scipy) + [mathematical-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-optimization) or something similar should be sufficient in all cases in my opinion. I've used the library plenty of times and I could help with a huge chunk of questions, yet I'd never think to watch a tag like [scipy-optimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scipy-optimize).

Comment: I somewhat disagree concerning [scipy-optimize]. Using [scipy] + [optimization] might cause some confusion because the [optimization] tag is also used by some to discuss possible code optimizations (speed-ups and improvements). Of course, one can use [mathematical-optimization] or [minimization] but that can be somewhat broad too.

Comment: @SuperKogito `might cause some confusion because the [optimization] tag is also used by some to discuss possible code optimizations` shouldn't they use the [performance] tag? Its description reads: *'For questions pertaining to the measurement or improvement of code and application efficiency.'*

Comment: @SuperKogito you're right, I didn't actually think about what tag to use (ironic). I indeed meant something like [tag:mathematical-optimization] or [tag:convex-optimization] as appropriate, I'll clarify my answer.